# Java while loop is doing three iterations by default

Tags: java, while-loop

I am beginning to learn Java and trying the while loop, I have written a simple program as a simple guessing game where the user tries to guess a letter between A and Z and the computer will print "correct" and repeats if the guessed letter is wrong, however, every time I try to run it the output is three iterations by default, I have tried to change the while loop to do-while and got the same output, I even added the int variable `i` as a counter to see if its really doing 3 iterations and the value of `i` always comes as 4 (3 wrong iterations when really it should be 1 plus one when I enter the correct answer).

Can you tell me what is the mistake I am doing?

```
class Guess {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        char answer = 'K', ignore, ch = 'a';
        int i=0;

        while (ch != 'K') {
            System.out.println("I am Thinking of a letter between A and Z, can you guess it?");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
            if (ch !='K') 
                System.out.println("Wrong ! please try again");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Correct!, you guessed after "+i+" attempts");
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all use answer in place of 'K' every where in the loop.Nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Please understand that proper code formatting isn't used to make your code "pretty" but rather to aid in your and *our* debugging. Please format it well, as this will help us both.

Comment: Your else block is missing.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, what does  *'the computer will print correct of repeats if the guessed letter is wrong'* mean?

Comment: @JavaFan i have added the else block and it still behaves the same

Comment: As pointed out in other answer its due to the newline character , use Scanner or check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, when you press **Enter** after typing the character in the console, the loop is executing once for the entered character and again once for the newline which is `10`.

So I just edited your code to skip the new line and wait for the next character to be entered, Also I moved the initial prompt outside of the loop. I hope this code would fix your issue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char answer = 'K', ignore, ch = 'a';
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("I am Thinking of a letter between A and Z, can  you guess it?");
        while (ch != 'K') {
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
            if(!Character.isLetter(ch)){
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Wrong ! please try again");
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("Correct!, you guessed after " + i + " attempts");

    }
```

Comment: thank you, this didnt fully solve the problem, now i get two printed lines of "Wrong! please try again" and the value of i becomes 3 (2 for two lines plus 1 for the correct K) but i guess you are correct, the loop executes again when i press enter

Comment: Are you sure, as the `continue` won't let the code reach till `System.out.println("Wrong ! please try again");` so it should be printed only once. I've tested this code and it is working flawlessly. So please check where you have used the `continue` it should be before the print statement.

Comment: yes i am pretty sure, I copied your code but i keep getting 2 iterations of the loop

Comment: Now its working like it should thanks a lot, what does !character do ?

Comment: `!Character.isLetter(ch)` checks if the entered character is an alphabet from the ASCII value, for others it will simply ignore the iteration of the loop, for e.g. if a number, blank space or an enter is given along with the input. Here is the ASCII chart:
http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look like.
Your code just missed the else block which is very necessary to break out of the loop,when the user guess the right character.I have added one.

```
class guess {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        char answer = 'K', ignore,ch='a';
        int i=0;

        while (ch != answer) {
            System.out.println("I am Thinking of a letter between A and Z, can you guess it?");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
            i++;
            if (ch !=answer) {
                System.out.println("Wrong ! please try again");
             }
             else{
                System.out.println("Correct!, you guessed after "+i+" attempts");
                break;
             }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi there I got a tip for you.
I personally would use a Scanner instead of System.in.read. A Scanner is an object that reads an input.

To create one, simply tipe this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //System.in referes to a console input
```

To know what the user typed use `sc.nextLine();`, which returns, as I said, the input. However it returns a String, not a char. So, in this case, you also needed to change the type of 'ch'.

To compare the answers with the input you will need to used the method `equals()`. Basically, if two things are the same, it returns true.

That said, your code should look like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = "K",ch;

    int i=0;
    boolean correct = false;
    while (!correct) { 
        System.out.println("I am Thinking of a letter between A and Z, can you guess it?");
        ch = sc.nextLine();
        i++;
        if (!ch.toUpperCase().equals(answer)) { // or ch.equals(answer) == false
            System.out.println("Wrong ! please try again");
         }else{ //if they are the same
             correct = true; //the answer is correct so you can leave the while loop
             System.out.println("Correct!, you guessed after "+i+" attempts");
         }

    }
    sc.close(); //you should always close a scanner after you use it, but you can ignore this step for now
```

Note that I also used a method called `toUpperCase()`. That method transform all the characters of the string to upper case, so, even if you type "k" instead of "K" you would also quit the loop.

Comment: I am getting an error executing your code, i will google how to use the scanner and give it a try

Comment: You have to import scanner. I forgot to mention it. Before ur class you need to write: import java.util.Scanner;